# Total derivative for complicated function

Tags: calculus

Suppose, $y = f(y - t)$, where f() is some function. How to calculate total differential?

The answer is $dy = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (dy - dt)$. I don't understand how to get this result. I used to deal with functions that are free from the variable they define, for example $y = f(x) \rightarrow dy = \frac{df}{dx} \cdot dx$.

My questions are:

1. How to deal with the fact that the dependent variable y is present inside the function?
2. Why do we take partial derivative wrt y? Should we somehow use partial derivative wrt t? For example: $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dt$.

Comment: Is this meant to be an implicit equation defining $y$ in terms of $t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider that $f$ is a function of a single variable, say $z:=y-t$. It's a composite function:
$$(y,t)\mapsto z=z(y,t)\mapsto f(z(y,t))\ .$$
Thus
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$
and
$$dz=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}dt\ .$$
Your result follows from the fact that $z(y,t)=y-t$ and thus $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}=-1$.

You see $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ just because $f$ depends on $y$ in the same way it would depend on $z$.

Comment: Thank you. The last line is unclear: what does it mean "depend in the same way"?

Comment: I meant simply that if you derive $f=f(z)$ with respect to $z$ and then substitute $z=y-t$ you obtain the same thing you would obtain taking just the derivative with respect to $y$  of $f(y-t)$.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes clearer if you write $f(y-t)=g(u)$ with $u=y-t$. Then 
$df=dg=g'(u)du=g'(u)(\partial_t u\  dt+\partial_y u\  dy)=g'(u) (-dt+dy)$. Then notice that $g'(u)=\partial _y f$

Answer (score 0):

I think about it as an implicit equation $\phi(y,t) = f(y-t)-y$. Then
${\partial \phi(y,t) \over \partial y} = {d f(y-t) \over dx} -1$,
${\partial \phi(y,t) \over \partial t} = -{d f(y-t) \over dx}$ and the
implicit function theorem gives
${d y(t) \over dt} = - {{\partial \phi(y,t) \over \partial t} \over {\partial \phi(y,t) \over \partial y}} = { {d f(y-t) \over dx} \over {d f(y-t) \over dx}-1 }$.